# DROP multiple tables at once in Azure Databricks

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I have two tables as below
Table 1: AllTablesInDatabase
Table 2: RequiredTablesInDatabase
Now, i want to drop all the table at a time which is not matching between these two tables using python or scala.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through you AllTablesInDatabase as a list and issue a drop table statement if it doesn't exist in your RequiredTablesInDatabase list